# How can I find the launch script that spring boot uses?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I want to see the exact script that spring boot uses when it executes my not fully executable jar. In particular I'm interested how it find the configuration (`.yml`) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command line args to specify the configuration files

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

For example

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/some-file.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `.yml` (if possible):

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
```

Or do you want to directly find your `.yml`?